# return disposable object outside of method

Tags: c#, idisposable

How to return `PdfDocument` outside of the method to read properties of the object? I understand that the method will throw the `object is disposed` exception because `using` will do the disposal job before it is returned.

I am asking for refactoring ideas. Maybe Actions fits here? Please provide with code ideas.

```
public PdfDocument Info(string inFile, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(inFile, new PdfStandardDecryptionHandler(password)))
            {
                return pdf;
            }
        }
        catch (IncorrectPasswordException)
        {
            throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FilePasswordProtected);
        }
        catch (UnexpectedStructureException)
        {
            throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FileDamaged);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `using` statement.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can't remove using because the object would not be closed. In long term, it will bring out of memory.

Comment: Then u need to refactor your code. You can't have a method that is suppose to return a `PdfDocument` if that same method is disposing of the `PdfDocument` before it's returned.

Comment: The consumer of `Info` should dispose the `PdfDocument`.

Answer (score 5):

The `using` statement is really syntactic sugar for a `try{}finally{}` construct and is lowered by the compiler as follows:

```
// this ...
using(var thing = new DisposableThing())
{
    ...
}

// gets rewritten to:
var thing = new DisposableThing();
try
{
    ...
}
finally
{
  if(thing is IDisposable)
  {
    ((IDisposable)thing).Dispose();
  }
}
```

So remove the `using` statement from your method to prevent premature disposal:

```
public PdfDocument Info(string inFile, string password)
{
    try
    {
        return new PdfDocument(inFile, new PdfStandardDecryptionHandler(password));
    }
    catch (IncorrectPasswordException)
    {
        throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FilePasswordProtected);
    }
    catch (UnexpectedStructureException)
    {
        throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FileDamaged);
    }
}
```

At which point the consumer becomes responsible for disposing of it:

```
using (var pdf = Info(inFile, password))
{
  // read properties from `pdf` here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to return a disposable object, then the caller function should handle the disposing; So, no need for the using statement inside the object creation function.

When you want call the Info function to create a PdfDocument object, use **try** to call "Info(string,string)" and then dispose it (if it's not null) in the **finally** block.

```
        public PdfDocument Info(string inFile, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(inFile, new PdfStandardDecryptionHandler(password));
                return pdf;
            }
            catch (IncorrectPasswordException)
            {
                throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FilePasswordProtected);
            }
            catch (UnexpectedStructureException)
            {
                throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FileDamaged);
            }
        }

        /////////////

        AnotherFunction()
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = null;

            try
            {
                pdf = Info("inFile", "password");
                // Use the object
            }
            finally
            {
                pdf?.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about turning the other way, not returning the object but injecting the Action?

```
    public void ProcessPdf(string inFile, string password, Action<PdfDocument> action)
    {
        try
        {
          using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(inFile, new PdfStandardDecryptionHandler(password)))
           {
             action (pdf);
           }
        }
        catch (IncorrectPasswordException)
        {
            throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FilePasswordProtected);
        }
        catch (UnexpectedStructureException)
        {
            throw new ApiException(ResponseMessageType.FileDamaged);
        }
    }
```

call it like:

```
ProcessPdf(iniPath, "*****", (o) => DoSomething(o))

private void DoSomething (pdfDocument doc)
{
  //....
}
```

pseudocode, not tested!